# getGraphics() method of the JFrame class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I see how the `getGraphics` method of `JComponent` classes can be useful. For e.g., that of a `JPanel` is particularly useful, but what exactly is the use of this method in the `JFrame` class?

Comment: `getGraphics method of JComponent classes can be useful` In what context? All painting should be done from within `paintComponent`, which accepts the Graphics object as a parameter, so their shouldn't be a need to call `getGraphics` when performing custom painting.

Comment: @copeg: Hmmm...you got a point there. How about if we want to create a buffered image. Then we would need this method.

Comment: *"How about if we want to create a buffered image."*  If I understand you correctly (and I really think I don't)  `new BufferedImage(w,h,type);`

Comment: So, the creator of Java had no specific purpose for this method?

Comment: Tip: Add @copeg (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify the person of a new comment.  The makers of Java sometimes defined methods needed by the toolkit but gave them wider access than they should.